# .NET application not taken default browser even set as default as edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge, default

I have one .NET application in which i have set default browser as Edge but it is taking internet explorer as a default browser . In internet explorer my some files are not working fine .

what setting should be change for set default as EDGE so all files can run properly?

Comment: _"I have one .NET application in which i have set default browser as Edge"_ <-- What do you mean by this?

Comment: How did you launch this application? Hyperlink or something else? Is it a desktop application or a web application or something else? If possible, could you provide more details?

Comment: It is desktop application.

Comment: Is there some way we can reproduce your issue? I think this will help solve the problem.